# Jquery get end date based on no of days and start date using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have input field(No. Of Days) with increase and decrease button and From and To date field.

When user select no of days by click on +/- button and select From date, end date should be calculated automatically based on no of days.
Also Promotion Amount should be calculated based on No of days in Promotion Amount field according to 10/- day.

**No of days field HTML:-**

```
<div class="field qty">
<label class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Of Days')) ?>:</label>
<div class="control">
    <div class="cart-qty">
        <div class="qty-ctl">
            <button title="<?= __('Decrease') ?>" type="button" data-role="change_cart_qty" class="up" data-qty="-1" class="decrease"></button>
        </div>
        <input type="number" class="qty" name="qty" id="noofdays" maxlength="12" value="<?= $defaultNoofDays * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($wmhelper->getNoofDaysValidation())) ?>" />
        <div class="qty-ctl">
            <button title="<?= __('Increase') ?>" type="button" data-role="change_cart_qty" data-qty="1" class="down"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="control">
    <label class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Banner From')) ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="promotion_from_date" id="promotion-from-date" class="input-text" value="" />
</div>


<div class="control">
    <label class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Banner To')) ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="promotion_to_date" id="promotion-to-date" class="input-text" value=""/>
</div>
```

I want to do this using jQuery, Can any one help me in this.

[image]

I am using below jQuery code and it give me previous click value in alert :-

```
    $('.up').on('mouseup', function add() 
{
    var $numberOfdays = $("#noofdays");
    var a = $numberOfdays.val();

    alert(a);
}); 

$('.down').on('mouseup', function subst() 
{
    var $numberOfdays = $("#noofdays");
    var b = $numberOfdays.val();
    alert(b);
});
```

Which event I want use to get after click value.

Comment: You did not explain what your specific problem is, you just gave us your “I want” wish list. This is not a code-writing service, so you need to do a bit better than that, if you want help here. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Let me just give you a simple example, it will work if you are using `datepicker`.
It will calculate your `promotion-to-date` on the basis of days changes and also changing `promotion-from-date`

```
    DateChangeWithDays();
    function DateChangeWithDays()
    {
        var days = parseInt($('#noofdays').val());

        var nextDayDate = $('#promotion-from-date').datepicker('getDate', '+'+days+'d');
        nextDayDate.setDate(nextDayDate.getDate() + days);
        $('#promotion-to-date').datepicker('setDate',nextDayDate);

        return true;
    }
```

Now call this function with days changing event and also `promotion-from-date` picker like this....

```
$('#promotion-from-date, #noofdays').change(function()
    {
      DateChangeWithDays();
    }
```